According to Pentecostal Protestantism, are the modern School of the Prophets in the same vein as the Old Testament "School of the Prophets:"?
Throughout the modern church world there exists Schools of the Prophets, many of which teach believers how to "prophesy" over individuals and congregations. For example:

Christian International School of Prophets (Bill Hamon, Florida)
Bethel School of Prophets (Redding, CA.)
Blue Ridge School of Prophets (Rocky Mount, VA)
Morningstar School of Prophets (Fort Mill, SC)
Portland Bible College (Church Life classes, Portland, OR)

Are these "schools" in the same tradition---and practice---as the Schools of the Prophets described in the Old Testament? [There were six cities that were seen as having these schools there: Ramah, Bethel, Gilgal, Jericho, Carmel, Samaria; see 1 Samuel 10, 19 and 2 Kings 2, 4, 6, 9, etc.] Note the research by Ira M. Price as to the existence of these bands or schools:

In the treatment of this subject the Old Testament will be used as the authority. Tradition and legend will not be considered. The endeavor shall be to examine and classify the information given concerning the sons of the prophets (1) as collected in bands or schools; (2) in particular localities; (3) under different teachers; (4) with specific instruction; (5) with an occupation; (6) as to their means of subsistence".  (Ira Price, "The Schools of the Sons of the Prophets," The Old Testament Student, Mar, 1889. Vol.  8, No. 7 pp. 244-249)


In conclusion, we have found in this brief discussion that the sons of the prophets (1) were collected together in bands or schools; (2) in six different localities, viz. (a) Ramah, (b) Bethel, (c) Gilgal, (d) Jericho, (e) Carmel, (f) Samaria; (3) under the tuition of (a) Samuel, (b) Elijah, (c) Elisha; (4) with instruction in (a) prophesying-worship, (b) sacred music, (c) practical matters of their day; (5) with their time wholly occupied in (a)study and worship, (b) doing errands for their masters and God, (c) performing the regular duties of a prophet; (6) largely dependent for their support upon the charity of the people. [Ibid]

Usually the modern "prophets" rest their justification for their supernatural ministries on the verses of Joel 2:28-29, Acts 2:14-18, and 1 Corinthians 12-14.

You men of Judea, and all that dwell in Jerusalem, be this known unto you, and hearken to my words: for these are not drunken, as you suppose, seeing it is but the third hour of the day.But this is that which was spoken by the prophet Joel: "And it shall come to pass in the latter days, saith God, I will pour out of my Spirit upon all flesh, and your sons and your daughters shall prophesy, and your young en shall see visions, and your old men shall dream dreams.And on my servants and on my handmaidens I will pour out in those days of My Spirit, and they shall prophesy. (Acts 2:14-18)

Have the modern prophets (graduates of the schools) exhibited legitimate prophetic ministry in their local churches equal to the ministries demonstrated in the Old Testament?
Are there "factual testimonies" to support their claims? Are there incidents beyond a reasonable doubt / coincidence that are irrefutable evidence of valid prophetic occurrences?
